# How I could animate changing UIViewControllers?

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, uiviewcontroller, transition

I have a UIViewController based app and I want to changes data on view with animation (handle `touchesbegan, touchesmove, touchesended`). All data I save in a base). For example, I have main screen, and when `(touches ended)` handles, I want to show other view.
[image: UiViewControllers images]

Whatever i will be to do, screens could be rotate (to right or to left, if position changes more then 1/2 of width View, but if labels count number more then count of rows in my table, I want to set state at image 2.

Could you see right way to do animations? For example, I could to create my own class or use app delegate, but I not sure from what I must to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UIView's transitionsWithView method:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:containerView
       duration:0.2
       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
       animations:^{ [fromView removeFromSuperview]; [containerView addSubview:toView]; }
       completion:NULL];
```

More details, including above example can be found here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816

Tim